# redirect subdomain to url on cloudflare

Tags: php, cloudflare

I need to set up a subdomain to redirect to a specific URL, not another domain. I'm using cloudflare.

I tried to do this by creating an A record pointing to the IP of the server and then I created a Page Rule which redirects from my subdomain to a specific address.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm totally lost, I find information on this anywhere.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it will be easier to make redirection with rewrite rules through .htaccess or virtual host configuration?

- At Cloudflare CP: create A record for subdomain in DNS section (if you don't have * A record already)
- At webserver: configure virtual host or/and add rewrite rules to redirect to needed
  URL

Answer (score 1):

There is a fairly extensive [tutorial about PageRules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-PageRules-) in our knowledge base & on our [blog](http://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-pagerules-url-forwarding).

Note: You do need to make sure the DNS record is proxied in your DNS settings for it to work. Redirects won't work if the record is going direct to your server.

Comment: thanks. i only need to wait ;). now works. i created promo a entry and a page rule for promo..... i only need the page rule or the dns entry too?

Comment: @damoncloudflare, what do you mean is proxied? Now my dns points to the server IP. how can i fix it, to make page rules work?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's a bug on cloudflare ( I already reported it )
If you have your subdomain record in place along with orange cloud proxy active and the correct url pattern and forwarding address set and it still refuses to work, then you are experiencing the -still to be confirmed- bug.

**This quick fix did the trick for me:**

1. Go to cloudflare settings.
   [image: domain settings contextual menu on cloudflare]
2. Change the "CDN only" performance setting to "CDN + basic optimizations".
   [image: contextual menu for performance settings and mouse indicating selection]

It will start working immediately, after that you can go back to "CDN only" and it will continue to work.